# Check presence of custom overload of function when template overload is available

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am designing an utility header that pumps binary data off an [`sf::InputStream`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1InputStream.php). For ease of use, is comprises a single function name, `readFromStream`, that has a lot of (templated and non-templated) overloads for automatically deserializing standard-layout types and type compounds like vectors, tuples and my custom-designed `grid` class. The complete implementation can be found here: https://github.com/JoaoBaptMG/ReboundTheGame/blob/master/MainGame/utility/streamCommons.hpp

So, I have defined an overload `readFromStream` that pumps out a vector of any type by calling `readFromStream` again recursively:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!is_optimization_viable<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
bool readFromStream(sf::InputStream &stream, std::vector<T> &value)
{
    size_t size;

    if (!readFromStream(stream, VarLength(size)))
        return false;

    std::vector<T> newVal(size, T());
    for (auto &val : newVal)
        if (!readFromStream(stream, val))
            return false;

    newVal.swap(value);
    return true;
}
```

I'd like to write an optimized version for standard-layout classes *for that there's not an overload for `readFromStream`*, so we can exploit the memory layout of them and blit them in a single `read` call:

```
// trait is_optimization_viable is what I'm having trouble to write
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<is_optimization_viable<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
bool readFromStream(sf::InputStream &stream, std::vector<T> &value)
{
    size_t size;

    if (!readFromStream(stream, VarLength(size)))
        return false;

    std::vector<T> newVal(size, T());
    if (stream.read(newVal.data(), size*sizeof(T)) != size*sizeof(T))
        return false;

    newVal.swap(value);
    return true;
}
```

Well, I could use a solution described on other answers to detect presence of a function, but there's a catch. When the type is standard-layout, I have a default `readFromStream` that reads like this:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_standard_layout<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
bool readFromStream(sf::InputStream &stream, T& value)
{
    return stream.read((void*)&value, sizeof(T)) == sizeof(T);
}
```

So, *there's always a function* that does the serialization, not just the one I wanted. The problem I want to solve here is: *how can I detect the presence of a non-default `readFromString` for type `T`, in order to disable the optimized version of `readFromString` for `std::vector<T>`*?

I have tried to pull a few tricks. I can't limit the optimization to POD types because I'm using `sf::Vector2<T>` on some types I want to deserialize, which is not POD. I tried to compare the function addresses I get when I use a non-templatized and templatized function, like:

```
using FPtr = bool(*)(sf::InputStream&, T&);
return (FPtr)readFromStream == (FPtr)readFromStream<T>;
```

But, strangely enough, it didn't work. And I researched *a lot* of solutions, but none I could adapt to what I needed. Maybe it's not possible in C++, and I'll have to resort "marking" the types I don't want to be optimized. Or maybe it's some obscure template I haven't thought of. How could I do this?

Comment: First of all you need some complementary `std::enable_if` clauses, because `std::is_standard_layout<T>` is probably not the opposite of `is_optimization_viable<T>` and you have an ambiguity at your hands.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, it's not the opposite; actually, the latter trait requires the former for what I need. I may not have described correctly what I want.

Comment: Why would you "disable the optimized version of readFromString"? If you want to check the presence of unusual serialization function then detection code would be basically the same as detection code checking for presence of usual serialization function, just with adjusted signature.

Comment: @VTT There are some standard-layout functions (like `std::string`, my own [`GameObjectDescriptor`](https://github.com/JoaoBaptMG/ReboundTheGame/blob/master/MainGame/data/RoomData.hpp) and basically everything with pointers) that are *not* supposed to be deserialized by fast blitting; so I want to check whether the presence of a particular overload exists so it's safer to use it.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/264088)

Comment: Are you sure that maybe you just want to use the is_trivial trait instead of is_standard_layout? is_trivial determines whether it is safe to treat the class as a bag of bytes. is_standard_layout is basically useful for nothing other than ABI interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it your problem is:

```
is_optimization_viable<T>;
```

could be defined by:

```
template<typename T>
using is_optimization_viable<T> = std::is_standard_layout<T>;
```

but for the fact that, for certain values of `T` that *are* standard layout
you nonetheless require a custom `bool readFromStream(sf::InputStream &stream, T &value)`, 
overload which means they are *not* optimization-viable.

Well as you must write these custom overloads, you know what those
exceptional values of `T` are. Say they are types `X`, `Y`, `Z`.
Then you can define the trait as:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename ...Us>
struct is_one_of;

template<typename T>
struct is_one_of<T> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T, typename First, typename ...Rest>
struct is_one_of<T,First,Rest...> {
    static constexpr bool value =
        std::is_same<T,First>::value || is_one_of<T,Rest...>::value;
};

// ^ C++17: `std::disjunction` does the job

template<typename T>
using has_custom_read_from_stream = is_one_of<T,X,Y,Z>;

template<typename T>
struct is_optimization_viable {

    static constexpr bool value = std::is_standard_layout<T>::value &&
        !has_custom_read_from_stream<T>::value;
};
```

I appreciate that you'd rather avoid the ongoing maintenance of the
hard-coded type-list `X`, `Y`, `Z`, and prefer somehow to SFINAE-probe
whether a call `readFromStream(s, t)` will be a call to one of the
custom overloads for some [`std::declval`-ed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) `s` and `t`.

But that's a mirage. You tell us, there will be *some* overload
`readFromStream(s, t)` that will compile whatever the type of `t`.
If so, a SFINAE probe will always tell you that *Yes,* `readFromStream(s, t)`
*will compile* - for any `T` as the unqualified type of `t`. And you
still have to make a compiletime decision as to whether `T` is one of
the custom types, and if not, whether it is standard-layout.

That's all there is to the problem. To tell whether `T` is one of
the custom types you must either test it for identity with any one
of them disjunctively, as shown, or your must find a trait independent of their
identities that is satisfied by all and only the custom types. As you
don't tell us what those custom types are, I can't suggest any such trait,
but if you find one then *it* will define or replace `has_custom_read_from_stream<T>`.

Incidentally, I second @NirFriedman's comment: is `std::standard_layout` really what you mean?

Comment: If it weren't for that pesky `sf::Vector2<T>`, I think `is_trivial` or even `is_pod` would suffice, but it's a dependency I cannot change.